# Posting form input value to the same page to build SQL connect string

Tags: php

I am trying to make a form's input value the trigger for a database connection; can anyone tell me what I am doing wrong please?

I thought I could post the value and on the page load after submission use the posted value as a variable to complete my connect string.

Code:

```
    <form name="form" action="Test.php" method="post">
&nbsp; <B>Please Enter Password</B>  &nbsp; <input type='password' name='test-' id ='password123';/>
<button id='test'>Submit Year</button>
</form>

    <?php   
$password= $_POST['password123'];


$conn = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','$password');
if (!$conn) {
    die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_select_db('ct', $conn);
?>
```

Comment: Your password field is delimited by apostrophes, so the password you are using is hardwired to the character sequence `$password`. Remove the surrounding quote marks to use the password in the variable called `$password`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
<?php

if ($_POST['do'] == 'something') {
    $conn = mysql_connect('localhost','root','$password') or die(mysql_error());
    mysql_select_db('ct', $conn);

    //Uncomment the below to prevent refresh spam
    //header("Location: {$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']}");
    //die();
}

?>
<form name="form" action="?process" method="POST">
    <input type='hidden' name='do' value='something'/>
    <strong>Please Enter Password</strong>
    <input type='password' name='test-' id ='password123'/>
    <button id='test'>Submit Year</button>
</form>
```

Consider using MySQLi also.

Comment: Please check again @Try_Fizzle use `REQUEST_URI` instead of `PHP_SELF` in the commented section in the code above.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
<form name="form" action="<?php $_SERVER['PHP_SELF']?>" method="post">
&nbsp; <B>Please Enter Password</B>  &nbsp; <input type='password' name='test-' id ='password123';/>
<button id='test' name="submit">Submit Year</button>
</form>

<?php   
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $password= $_POST['test-'];
    $conn = @mysql_connect('localhost','root','$password');
    if (!$conn) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
    }
    mysql_select_db('ct', $conn);
}
?>
```